# Table float with the container overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I want to show two table in same line. Then I'm using `float: left;` [Like this.](http://jsfiddle.net/bULcB/2/)

If those tables width more than the container I use `overflow: hidden;` to hide the surplus.

Overflow hidden working perfect but the table not stay at the same line.

http://jsfiddle.net/bULcB/3/

How can I fix that. I want the table stay at the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a container `div` to wrap the two tables. And then make its `width` great enough to hold the two tables in a line. The overflow part of the container will not be shown as the parent `div` has specified `overflow: hidden;`.

See updated example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/YAaL4/)

Answer (score 1):

Give `position: relative` to your parent element and give `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100px;` to your **second** child element (remove `float` property from second child element).

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bULcB/5/)**

**or else**

Give `White-space: nowrap` to your parent element and give `display: inline-block` to your child elements instead of `float: left`.

Works only in latest version of browsers.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bULcB/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
div style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden; ">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float: left;  background-color:red;">
    <tr>
        <td>First Table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float: left; background-color:yellow;">
    <tr>
        <td>Second Table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```